# angular 4 observable catch service undefined

Tags: angular, undefined, observable

I have a service to work with the interact with the backend.  The am looking to catch 401 status, indicating the user has been logged out by the backend (token expiration).  So when I catch a 401, I save off the current route, and navigate them to the login page.  However, when I catch the error, the router service is undefined.  Is this something to do with observables?

```
@Injectable()
export class SiteService {
private url : string = "site";
constructor(
    private http: Http, 
    private authService : AuthenticationService,
    private router : Router,
    private globals : Globals
    ){}

addSite(site : Site) : Observable<Site> {
    let data = new URLSearchParams();
    data.append('auth', this.authService.getToken());
    const options = new RequestOptions({
        params: data
    });
    return this.http.post(this.url, site, options).map(response => {
        return toSite(response.json().data);
    }).catch(this.handleError);

}
changeSite(site : Site) : Observable<Site> {
    let data = new URLSearchParams();
    data.append('id', this.authService.getToken());
    const options = new RequestOptions({
        params: data
    });
    return this.http.post(`${this.url}/${site.siteName}`, site, options).map(response => {
        return toSite(response.json().data);
    }).catch(this.handleError);
}


private handleError(error : any) {
    let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message : error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
    console.error(errMsg);
    if((error.status == 403 || error.status == 401) &&(error.json().error.indexOf("token") >= 0)){
        this.globals.nextLocation = this.router.url;
        this.router.navigate(['login']);
    }
    return Observable.throw(error);
}
```

}

Comment: `console.log(error)` inside the handleError and update the screenshot

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Replace

```
catch(this.handleError)
```

by

```
catch(error => this.handleError(error))
```

Otherwise, you're not binding the handleError function to `this`.

Also note that the proper status code for your status would be 401, not 403.

Comment: You are correct about 401 - unfortunately some people on the team decided to use 403 instead of 401, and was not caught during reviews. So both have to be handled, and subsequently a string comparison...horrible.  Thanks.  I knew it was something simple..